# can't find my office 365 directory/subscription ID

Tags: office365

probably a stupid question but I can't find my subscription/directory ID in office 365. Google didn't help much.

I've tried to look into the subscription in the admin portal but I can't see it.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

To find the Office 365 subscription ID:

1. You need to be an admin on your o365 subscription to access this info.
2. Go to backstage of any office application and click on office account option to find the same on the rhs.

For more information, please review the following link:

[Would anyone know where I can find the Office 365 subscription ID?](https://www.quora.com/Would-anyone-know-where-I-can-find-the-Office-365-subscription-ID)